# Difference among Azure batch, scheduler and web job and when to use what

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-scheduler, azure-batch

I could see primarily there are 3 options in Windows Azure to schedule jobs. Batch, scheduler and web jobs. Is there any link or video explaining what are the differences and what to use when and benefits?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So far I didn't see anything official from azure.com or msdn, so let me take a stab.

**Azure Batch** - is a way to run parallel (typically compute intensive) HPC style job on the cloud. Batch pitches the value of parallel job running as a service so you don't worry about provisioning/managing large cluster. A typical scenario is, go encoding those 10K H.264 videos from 1080p to 720p - instead of spinning up 200 VMs you just configure the command line and specify the location of those 10k videos (blobs).

**Azure Scheduler** is a way to run recurring job at specified time. It's Windows Task Scheduler in cloud. For example, start a cloud service 8AM every weekday and shut it down at 6PM.

**Azure Web Job** is focusing on doing background job for Azure Website. It's working daemon web server farm in cloud. An example is - compress all images uploaded from the webpage.

Comment: I have 450 x 50GB tar files to unpack after MS has received the disk. Should I use webjobs or batch? These tars typically take days to untar on a single machine but not sure which approach is preferred - only heard about Azure Batch today! thanks

Comment: Note that Azure Scheduler has been retired.  You should use Logic Apps instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/migrate-from-scheduler-to-logic-apps

Comment: 1) can azure scheduler process files having 1 million records and insert that into Azure SQL database ? 2) Can we configure and run C# console apps in Azure scheduler 3) if above is true , will azure scheduler be cheaper option than azure batch ?

Comment: Azure Scheduler was fully retired and not available. It has replaced by Azure Logic App

Answer (score 7):

To add to Yiding answer, **Azure Scheduler** and **Azure WebJobs** actually work together and complete each other in that sense.

**Azure WebJobs** will host your code/executable that is doing the work.
**Azure Scheduler** will schedule when to run your work --> WebJob.

To start create a scheduled Azure WebJob which will create both resources.

Comment: Can `Azure WebJobs` do any processing/calculations etc as well or that functionality can only be done via `Azure Batch`?